# Does the eyedropper in Photoshop CS5 behave differently than in CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, cs5, hex, eyedropper

I'm having this weird issue where I received PSDs to work on, and I'm on a Mac if that has anything to do with it, and I've eye-dropped colors here and there from the darkest pixel whenever the designers haven't used a hex value and opted for opacity instead since I need the hex for web development.

Now these same PSDs on another person's computer, a PC, and using CS6 whereas I'm using CS5, is eye-dropping the same exact things I am - and is getting a totally different hex value.

I can't make sense of it - the person suggested maybe the strength of their back-light on their monitor might affect it, but that can't be it... right? How do I know which hex values are correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set the color preferences to be the same on both machines? Calibrated the monitors properly?

Comment: When you say color preferences, do you mean making sure the PSDs on both machines are both using RBG for example, under Image > Mode? And the monitors do make a difference? How would I calibrate the monitors?

Comment: Edit > Color Settings and check your monitor preferences for calibration there.

Comment: I checked the color settings as you suggested and they match on both PS versions/computers. I also noticed that it only happens when we're not eye-dropping something that isn't a totally solid color. So as an experiment, we both eye-dropped a red button and it was the same color. With font, however, on the darkest line of the "n" pictured above, I got 7f7f7f and she got a3a3a3. Maybe it's a weird font thing? We eye-dropped the same exact dark line in the letter "n".

Comment: Is it the *exact* same Photoshop document? And the monitors have been accurately calibrated? And the EyeDropper tools are both set tot he *exact* same sampling size?

Comment: Yes - same exact PSD. Monitors with the same settings as pictured above. And sampling the same exact pixel. The only differences are I'm on CS5 and she's on CS6. I'm on a Mac and she's on a PC, but we tried in CS5 on someone else's PC and he was getting the colors I was - so I think it's more Photoshop version than it is platform. And it looks like the issue happens with fonts more than something that's a solid color.